# Image not appearing in <div> tags

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a website with navigation bar. My image/background from css does not appear in my index.php. Can anyone help me with this?

My coding as follows:

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>xxx</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="headerbg">
  <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="navMenu">

<ul>
<li><a class="BANNER" href="index.php">Home</a>
</li> <!-- end main LI -->
</ul> <!-- end main UL -->

</div> <!-- end navMenu -->
</div> <!-- end wrapper div -->
</div> <!-- end headerbg -->

<div id="footerbg">
  <div id="content">Content for  id "content" Goes Here</div>
Content for  id "footer" Goes Here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

admin.css

```
#headerbg {
    background: url('../Images/header.png') no-repeat fixed center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#footerbg {
    background: url('../Images/footer.png') no-repeat fixed right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Problems:

1) I couldn't see the image at my headerbg id and footerbg id.

2) How do I align the text within content to next line?

Comment: The Image path is right?

Comment: Check the image path first by using the image tag on the html itself. It might be causing the issue

Comment: I didn't understand you #2 question. Can you explain?

Comment: Get to know the tools of the trade, Firebug for Firefox and Chrome Developer tools. These tools will enable you to see if all your resources have been downloaded using the "Net" tab. You will also be able to inspect your element with the missing image, where once again you will be able to determine if you have got the path right. An aditional tip is to use root relative paths if possible,e.g: `/Images/footer.png`

Comment: Also, if you have two questions, ask them seperately.

Comment: may be problem is because of capital letter check if it is Images or images

Answer (score 0):

1. background-size is supported only in IE9+ (and of course FF and chrome) If you use IE8 or IE7 - It won't work. You can add width and height to headerbg css. And of course check the image path (maybe it's wrong):

   ## headerbg {

   ```
   background: url('../Images/header.png') no-repeat fixed center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100%;
   height:100px;
   width:100px;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Your image path is wrong. I checked it changing image path. it works fine

You can check placing your images into same directory of your html file and give src= only file name with extension

[See the js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/71fghkLb/)

```
#headerbg {
    background: url('http://www.bedlamrealty.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/chain-link1.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#footerbg {
    background: url('http://www.bedlamrealty.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/chain-link1.jpg') no-repeat fixed right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Header must have a `height` attribute or it must have some contents to give it some height so try adding this css

```
#headerbg {
height:3em; //change it accordingly.
}
```

**Edit**

There is an alternate that you can apply. Use `img` tag to make background image.